# CRM 2015 Automation Testing using selenium, Change Focus after Click

Tags: java, internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver, dynamics-crm-2015

I'm using **Selenium** scripts using Java to automate a project in **CRM 2015**. When I tried to click on a button using IE Webdriver it navigates correctly but focus still on clicked button and then cannot find any controls as It's implement using Single App page. Could you please give me workaround ? I tried :

```
driver.switchTo().defaultcontent();
driver.switchTo().ActiveElement();
```

but not working and still on clicked button focus.

Comment: Actually your question is not clear.. could you explain more??

Comment: Reading the WebDriver javadocs tells us that switch is used to switch to a different window or frame, which given it sounds like you are automating a single page app isn't what you want to do.  If its an ajax page you should expose the Ajax classes, if it is just using javascript to manipulate the page layout you should just be able to wait for the script to process and then access the elements as normal.

Comment: @Saurabh Gaur   I mean that webdriver still clicks on control that already clicked after navigation done but with different control with same Xpath. So when attempt to find another element driver is too busy by keeping click on button and get no such webelement error. Here is sample of code: '  WebElement New_button = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='Mscrm.DashboardTab.Case.NewCase']/span"));
  New_button.click();                   
'

Comment: @Gavin You means that I can change focus using javascript using executescript() method in selenium ? I think this may help but not sure if it works properly with IE webdriver or not.

Comment: @M.Sedky: why did you derive this conclusion: "So when attempt to find another element driver is too busy by keeping click on button and get no such webelement error."? If you have another element with the same xpath, then your xpath is a problem, you either need to make it more unique, or you need to get all elements with this xpath, and then choose the one you are looking for. Also usually the "no such webelement error" is received when you try "find element" too quickly after changing page. Instead, try to wait for it using `WebDriverWait.until`

Comment: @M.Sedky what do you mean still click on same control?? If you are providing same xPath on same page obviously it will click on same control because when you use `findElement` it will always gives first element with matching locator. You need to use more unique locator which points only single element then you could defenetely see that WebDriverWait would never busy for same locator.. Actually there is no sense to say that driver is busy. It works as you that you provide command as like robot so it works according to you, it never do work with himself.So Please omit this from your mind...:)

Comment: Thanks for all. I find the solution it's mix between change focus to mainframe and implicitwait to load all elements in the page. Here is sample of code           driver.switchTo().frame(0);         driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);